# Pasar datos de un componente Vue a otro, a través del controlador. VUE + LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Dentro de un componente A tengo un parámetro que necesito para poder realizar una consulta SQL y poder mostrarlos dentro del componente B el problema es que los componentes están en distintos Blades.php entonces cuando me dirijo a la otra pagina se pierden los datos al momento de actualizar o eso creo yo, ya que intente enviar el parámetro mediante props y Eventbus pero ni siquiera se muestran.

Dentro del componente A tengo esto que me envia el parametro hacia el controlador para efectuar la busqueda:

```
envioId(item){
            axios.get(`/Admin/listitems/${item.id}`).then(res => {
                // console.log(res.data);
            });
        }
```

Dentro del controlador tengo esto que me retorna la busqueda hecha:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $items = \DB::table('items')->select('id','nombre_item','A_cargo', 'id_subcategoria')->where('id_subcategoria',$id)->get();
        return $items;
    }
```

Como hago para pasar esa busqueda al componente B sin que se pierdan los datos en el momento que se refresca la pagina al cambiar de blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de dos formar:

1. Desde el lado del servidor con [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session) de laravel dependiendo de la version de laravel mira la documentación.
2. Desdel el lado del cliente utilizando localstorage [creando tu codigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) o [con le gestion de paquetes javascript  npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-storage)

Creo que hay mas, pero esas son las se me vinieron a la cabeza.